# Mid-transaction SELECTs. How to include Procedure changes to those SELECTs?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to SELECT a record from a table that a Store Procedure has modified and retrieve it in the uncommitted state within the same SQL transaction?

Broken down...

1. Start Transaction.
2. Retrieve Record A.  Store in Object 1.
3. Execute SP that modified Record A.
4. Retrieve Record A.  Store in Object 2.
5. End Transaction.

**Result** - Object #1 and #2 are the same.  I want them to be different.  Where Object #2 includes the changes from the Stored Procedure that executed that happened to modified Record A.

---

**EDIT**

I've narrowed it down further.  On step #4, I'm making two calls to retrieve Record A:

- createSQLQuery -> print results -> Shows the **correct** data from Step #3.
- createQuery -> print results -> Shows **stale** data from Step #3.

My guess right now is that Hibernate's first-level query cache is holding on to Record A and just giving it back to me rather than execute another SELECT.  *I'm not sure yet the best way to get around this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute the stored procedure, you need to `clear()` your hibernate session to force the updated data to be retrieved from the database.

Comment: There is something else at play.  I call `session.flush()` before and after SP execution to make sure DB state is correct before SP execution and that the SP state is available back to the transaction (supposedly) after it has been executed.

Comment: @JohnStrickler - are you sure that you are using the same transaction for the stored procedure?  also, are you using a second-level cache?  also, `flush()` is _different_ from `clear()` (flush pushes changes to the db but does not clear the session, i don't believe).  did you try a clear after the flush?

Comment: I narrowed it down further.  It looks like the first-level cache is getting in the way.  If I use createSQLQuery and retrieve the data it is correct.  If I use createQuery and retrieve an entity list then they are in an improper state from before the SP was called.  Still no solution though.

Comment: @JohnStrickler - did you try actually calling `clear()`?  that should remove any cached data from the first-level cache.

Comment: That fixed it and it seems like the ideal solution.  Seems like anytime I use a stored procedure that alters the state of my entities then I'd want to flush/clear the session.

Comment: @JohnStrickler - yes that is required for any "external" modification (changes made outside of hibernate).